# mysql query for each of the values of an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$gsayi-1; $i++)
  {
    $a[] = mysql_result($aylik,$i);
  }
foreach ($a as $value)
  {
    $m = mysql_query("SELECT puan FROM sorular WHERE ID = $value");
    echo $m; 
  }
```

a[ ] array is

2,2,1

I am trying to execute a mysql query with each of that values. I am using that values as ID.

I tried foreach loop but it shows me `Resource id #7Resource id #7`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you have 2, 2, 1, your first two `echo`s will be the same

Comment: I made it 2,1 and I want to do 

SELECT puan FROM sorular WHERE ID = 2
SELECT puan FROM sorular WHERE ID = 1

but in a functional way as you understand from my question

Comment: What is $aylik? Would it be possible to combine the two queries into one so you do not need to loop twice?

Comment: $aylik is a query that takes question id's which user solved from a table in a certain period of time.

Comment: Note that the mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. All new code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have many advantages, including prepared statements. Instead of interpolating values directly into the statement, you should use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), which lets you re-use the query and keeps the value separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fetch the result

```
$m = mysql_query("SELECT puan FROM sorular WHERE ID = $value");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($m);
echo $result['puan'];
```

Comment: now the results are 3,4
when I do array_sum($result) it shows me 4 not 7. Can you help me about that also?

Comment: You have to be careful with the type of your values in this array.
This should be int value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the results in some form.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

mysql_query returns a resource...not the results of the query. To get the results you have to use one of the mysql_fetch_* functions, in this example we fetch an object with the query results.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Try something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$gsayi-1; $i++) {
    $a[] = mysql_result($aylik,$i);
}
foreach ($a as $value) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT puan FROM sorular WHERE ID = $value");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result) {
        echo $value . ' = ' . $row->puan . ' | ';
    }
}
```

Comment: now the results are 3,4. when I do array_sum($result) it shows me 4 not 7. Can you help me about that also?